# Create a unique list of values that match a criteria, sorted in order of another criteria

Tags: excel, list, sorting, unique, distinct-values

I've been struggling with this question for a week.

In column E I have the following formula to create a distinct list of values in A for which the date in column B matches the date in E1. The formula is:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        $A$2:$A$976,
        MATCH(
            0,
            IF(
                $E$1=$B$2:$B$976,
                COUNTIF($E$1:$E1, $A$2:$A$976),
                ""
            ),
            0
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

This formula works.

What I want to do is sort the results of this formula based on the corresponding value in column C in ascending order.

In column G is the way it should look.

I also want to display those ascending column C values in column F. Column H is the way F should look.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

[image]